# Windows Task scheduler does not run my python script

Tags: python, import, window, task, scheduler

I'm trying to run my python script using the window task scheduler but it wont work.
When I run the script manualy it is working fine. I rode that I had to create a batch file to then run it into the window task scheduler. But nothing happend when I click run (in the window task scheduler).

Here's is the BAT code :
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Users\leoli\Desktop\stock"
"C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe" "C:\Users\leoli\Desktop\stock\main.py"

The main.py has this code :

```
def writeInFile(txt) :
    with open('C:\\Users\\leoli\\Desktop\\stock\\windowstaskscheduler.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write("test: " + txt)

#import functions: 
from fetchData import fetchData
from stock_price_graph import get_graph_stock_price
from send_email import send_email

# Import companies name and limits 
from companies_list import companies

writeInFile('23')

import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)

for company in companies:
    key = list(company.keys())[0]
    limit_min_value = company[key]["limit_min"]
    
    dateArray, close_prices, dict_close, current_price = fetchData(key, limit_min_value)

    if current_price < limit_min_value: 
        print("email will be send")
        send_email(key, limit_min_value, current_price)
```

I think the problem comes from the importation of the module.

The window task scheduler action settings look like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peOf0.png)

for info the folder containing all the necessary files to run this code are in a single folder named "stock"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WONaG.png)

Do you see what could be the issue ?

I'm trying to run a python code automaticaly using the window task scheduler. But it seems that the 'import module' from the python file make the execution failed.